# Use Exceptions in if condition

Tags: java, exception, firebase-authentication

Im using `Firebase Auth` in order to manage my login and register for the app.

I had like to add toast messages based on the exception that I receive.

For example, if the exception is from `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` I had like to toast one message. If it is from `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` then I had like to use another toast.

I use something like:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( SignUpActivity.this );
                    View toastview = inflater.inflate( R.layout.toast_registered, null );
                    Toast toast = new Toast( SignUpActivity.this );
                    toast.setView( toastview );
                    toast.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER, 0, 3 );
                    toast.setDuration( Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                    toast.show();
                }

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "toast1." + task.getException(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "toast2." + task.getException(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

So basically I need to add something to the if condition however im not sure what.

I saw a use of `catch` but I dont think this is the situation.

Thank you

Comment: You will be showing 2 toasts here in the case of a failed auth. See my answer, it handles each fail case that you state in your question once and only once and removes redundant checks. In my answer, I assume you only want to start SignupActivity if the auth failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( SignUpActivity.this );
                    View toastview = inflater.inflate( R.layout.toast_registered, null );
                    Toast toast = new Toast( SignUpActivity.this );
                    toast.setView( toastview );
                    toast.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER, 0, 3 );
                    toast.setDuration( Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                    toast.show();
                }
                else {
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                         Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "toast1." + task.getException(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                         Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "toast2." + task.getException(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }   
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

So, you check if task was successful, if not you switch on error type and show corresponding toast before starting signup activity and finishing this activity.

Comment: Sorry, it's instanceof, updating my answer now (not lowercase o in Of)

Comment: It is a keyword in Java, used for checking if a variable is an instance of a class

Comment: Are those the only two exceptions that can happen? If not, or if they ever add a third, you should have another `else` as a catch-all, otherwise the user won't see any toast.

Comment: Not guaranteed, so you raise a good point. For the OP - as David is saying; always check for the edge case - in this instance that is the generic exception. But as the OP question was about 2 exception types in particular my answer should address that.

Comment: That is domain logic anyway, perhaps there is a reason to not show a toast in the generic case? My answer should address the crux of the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need only one condition like task.isSuccessful().

You can do something like that:

```
if(task.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
        throw task.getException();
    } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
        /*Toast here*/
    } catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
        /*Toast here*/
    } catch(...) ...
}
```

With

```
...
throw task.getException();
...
```

you will throw the specific exception and with

```
} catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
    /*Toast here*/
}
```

you will catch the specific exception to handle that and do what you want, in your case you will write code to show toast inside catch statement.

Remember to catch all exceptions or when unhandled exception is thrown your app will crash.

You can also handle generic exception:

```
if(task.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
        throw task.getException();
    } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
        /*Toast here*/
    } catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
        /*Toast here*/
    } catch(Exception e) {
        /*Handle generic exception*/
    }
}
```

Bye

Comment: why on earth would you try to throw the exception that has already been thrown and captured in the underlying framework?

Comment: You also don't need the check for !isSuccessful(), because by definition the first check checks the inverse of this so you can just use else...

Comment: @ThomasCook Yes, sorry, i just copied code from the Answer. Anyway, i don't like use multiple conditions, i think that try-catch is clear and easy to read.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's really bad advice. You are performing a try whose sole purpose is to throw an already caught exception in order to use the catch mechanism to perform a type check that is completely do-able using instanceof.

Comment: Try should be performing something that could fail, not for doing something that *will* fail. It's kind of in the name 'try'. The framework has already 'tried' to do the risky work and has even gone to the lengths of wrapping up the failure in the value passed to the callback so you can AVOID using a try catch on the consuming end